# MYSQL COUNT WITH 3 DISTINCT

Tags: mysql

Hi I have this VISITS table

[image]

What I want to achieve:

```
**affiliate_id** **unique visits count** 

167               4
121               1
137               1
```

Special Condition is one IP can only be counted once per day for single affiliate_id.

So for visit_id 553 and 554, it can be only counted as one visits because both have same ip, same date and same affiliate_id.

From what I understand I need to group by ip, date and affiliate_id and count it, but not sure how to write the query.

Can you guys point me to some reference or insight to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

--

Update with link sample SQL:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3765168/tb_visits.sql

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly,

```
SELECT affiliate_id, count(*) 
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT affiliate_id, ip, DAY(date)
          FROM visits) AS q
  GROUP BY affiliate_id;
```

Comment: Thanks but the query group all visits into one affiliate_id only as in picture below

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3765168/query2.png

Comment: Sorry I had been too hasty. Edited.

Comment: Thanks sir your query is exactly what I need after scrathing my head for a day before coming to StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirement i think you need  the distinct ip per date and affiliate_id

```
 select DATE(date), affiliate_id, count(distinct( ip))
 from your_table
 group by DATE(date), affiliate_id
```

Comment: Thanks but the query not grouping by affiliate_id as in picture below

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3765168/query1.png

Comment: Hi @Dario answer is the most correct, however your answer also give me something that I need, so I am giving you vote for your assistant. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is group the number of unique or distinct ip's for a given `affiliate_id` so the only group by you need is the `affiliate_id`. The Unique hits are calculated using a count and to make then unique you add the `DISTINCT` key word

```
SELECT 
    affiliate_id, COUNT(DISTINCT ip) AS unique_visit_counts, 
FROM tablename
GROUP BY affiliate_id
```

However since you want it by the day as well you might want to include a date clause such as:

```
DATE_FORMAT(date, "%y-%m-%d") AS `date`
```

Which will turn your date and time stamp into a day in the YY-MM-DD format.

If you group by that you can get a full list by day by affiliate_id using something like

```
SELECT 
    affiliate_id, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT ip) AS unique_visit_counts, 
    DATE_FORMAT(date, "%y-%m-%d") AS `date`  
FROM tablename
GROUP BY `date`, affiliate_id
```

Or pick a specific date using something like

```
SELECT 
    affiliate_id, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT ip) AS unique_visit_counts, 
FROM tablename
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, "%y-%m-%d") = '17-02-08'
GROUP BY affiliate_id
```

Comment: Hi Dave thanks for your insight, I did try your query but it still not grouping by affiliate_id as in picture below

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3765168/notgroupingbyid.png

I upload sample SQL with data for reference

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3765168/tb_visits.sql

Comment: Is there a reason why IP needs to be `tinytext`? can it be `varchar(255)` or better yet `varchar(40)`. It seems like a waste if you're only storing an IP in there. Anyway `DISTINCT` doesn't work with text type fields in SQL so you'll have to either change it (preferred) or `CAST` it  `CAST(ip as varchar(255))` Haven't tested the code yet but something like ... `COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(ip as varchar(255)))` Might work?

Comment: Hi the IP tinytext is out of my control since it was a table from third party library / extension. I have accepted the other answer but your help is really appreciated. Thanks again sir for your kind soul.

Comment: np Best of luck to you. I'm glad that you found your answer but I will express a bit of my concern with the use of the `DAY()` function if you plan on having data that spans over a month. `https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth` Might cause some unexpected results, unless that's what you're going for. In which case I'm way in left field. `DATE()` maybe more what you're looking for with that answer.